# Python Regex - remove all "." and special characters EXCEPT the decimal point

Tags: python-3.x, regex, regex-group, regexp-replace, nsregularexpression

I have some sentences with multiple "."s.

How can I remove all special characters and '.' in the data except the decimal point?

The Input Example is

```
What? The Census Says It’s Counted 99.9 Percent of Households. Don’t Be Fooled.
```

and I want to remove all "." s and special characters EXCEPT the decimal point'.'

The output should be like

```
What The Census Says Its Counted 99.9 Percent of Households Dont Be Fooled
```

I tried this ,

```
regex = re.compile('[^ (\w+\.\w+)0-9a-zA-Z]+')
regex.sub('', test)
```

But the output was

```
What The Census Says Its Counted 99.9 Percent of Households. Dont Be Fooled.
```

Comment: You can't put groups in brackets. Try '[^ .0-9a-zA-Z]+'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a capturing group to capture only the decimal numbers and at the same time match special chars (ie. not of space and word characters).

Upon replacement, just refer to the capturing group in-order to make use of only the captured chars. ie. the whole match would be removed and replaced by the decimal number if exists.

```
s = 'What? The Census Says It’s Counted 99.9 Percent of Households. Don’t Be Fooled.'
import re
rgx = re.compile(r'(\d\.\d)|[^\s\w]')
rgx.sub(lambda x: x.group(1), s)
# 'What The Census Says Its Counted 99.9 Percent of Households Dont Be Fooled'
```

OR

Match all the dots except the one exists between the numbers and all chars except special chars and then finally replace those match chars with an empty string.

```
re.sub(r'(?!<\d)\.(?!\d)|[^\s\w.]', '', s)
# 'What The Census Says Its Counted 99.9 Percent of Households Dont Be Fooled'
```

Answer (score 1):

You need the following regex:

```py
[^ 0-9a-zA-Z](?!(?<=\d\.)\d)
```

Or, if you need a fully Unicode aware regex:

```py
(?:_|[^\s\w])(?!(?<=\d\.)\d)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VVGGYM/1). *Details*:

- `[^ 0-9a-zA-Z]` - any one char other than a space, ASCII letter or digit
- `(?:_|[^\s\w])` - a `_` char or any one char other than whitespace and word char
- `(?!(?<=\d\.)\d)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match, if there is a digit immmediately to the right of the current location that is immediately preceded with a digit and a dot.

See a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/9gyVCA):

```py
import re
s = 'What? The Census Says It’s Counted 99.9 Percent of Households. Don’t Be Fooled.'
print(re.sub(r'[^ 0-9a-zA-Z](?!(?<=\d\.)\d)', '', s))
# => What The Census Says Its Counted 99.9 Percent of Households Dont Be Fooled
print(re.sub(r'(?:_|[^\s\w])(?!(?<=\d\.)\d)', '', s))
# => What The Census Says Its Counted 99.9 Percent of Households Dont Be Fooled
```